# iPhone 4 passcode lock disabled and no access to iTunes

Tags: iphone, security

My phone is disabled and I have no access to iTunes. It is telling me to try again in 23,805,632 seconds but of course I can't wait 50 years!

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly get going again by erasing the device and restoring from iTunes.

The backup doesn't need to be in iTunes, but if you don't have a backup, you may be starting over.

See http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1212 for an up to date explanation from Apple as well as more details on the process for your computer or OS of choice.